# Is bootstrap interfering with my Jqueryui or am i missing something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Trying to put Jqueryui Sortable interaction into a Bootstrap table so people can move rows around to compare them.

So is the Jqueryui not compatable with Bootstrap? Can I not put table rows in lists? Like what is the problem here? Im not understanding the issue cause none of the rows are sortable/moving.

HTML and JS-

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Bombers Hockey_files/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/bootstrap.min.js.download" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="./Bombers Hockey_files/hockey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/popper.min.js.download"></script>

      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
      } );
      </script>

    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>GP</th> 
        <th>Goals</th>
        <th>Assists</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Penalties</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
    <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>12</td> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Braden</td>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Caleb</td>
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Ryan</td>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Kyle</td>
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Sean</td>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Seth</td>
        <td>11</td> 
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>47</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Kyle Z</td>
        <td>8</td> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Gary</td>
        <td>10</td> 
        <td>7</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>12</td> 
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>30</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
       <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>12</td> 
        <td>1</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </tbody></table>
```

CSS -

```
 #sortable { 
  list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; 
}

 #sortable li { 
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; 
}

 #sortable li span { 
  position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arranging your link and script tags and see if that does it. It could be case of something overriding something else:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Bombers Hockey_files/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./Bombers Hockey_files/hockey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/bootstrap.min.js.download" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
<script src="./Bombers Hockey_files/popper.min.js.download"></script>
```

Comment: Copied and tried what you have for arrangement and still nothing. The rows themselves aren't even target-able to move, which makes me think rows are not able to be put into list items. Idk this whole thing has me confused, been staring at code to long.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `<ul><li>` tags inside `<tbody>` are invalid and unnecessary as `<tr><td>` elements are basically lists.  Just making the `<tbody>` of your table sortable works just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/66mj031n/